# Collaborative process management ideally with document output

Tags: project-management, collaboration, process-control

> ***Disclaimer:** I will try to describe my problem into much detail to hopefully make you understand what I want. I apologise for the length of this.*

## Our current process management

1. When a new process starts a document is created from the template by the process manager (person A). The document basically holds the metadata of the process.
2. The document is edited by person A who fills in the initial metadata info and prints it out and hands it over to person B for further processing.
3. Person B starts doing its tasks related to the process and adds task outputs (other digital files) metadata to the document, writing filenames and their descriptions by hand on the printed document.
4. When all tasks are finished, person B hands the document back to person A.
5. Person A makes their own outputs (digital files) using outputs of person B.
6. Person A then hands over some of their outputs to person C that produces their own outputs and returns them (they don't get the process document).
7. When the process is complete, the document is physically saved in a folder for future purposes, so that outputs can be found on backups whenever needed.

Person A is the manager of the process and has to collaborate with all others to bring the process to the end.

## The problems we're facing

- Process flow document is printed in physical form, so person A cannot know the state of a particular document when it's in person B's possession without asking them.
- The document may get lost for whatever reason because people are taking the document to wherever they produce their outputs (usually always out of the office).
- Even if person B finishes their tasks and forgets to bring the document with them, person A is stalled from furthering the process because they lack metadata to finish their tasks proceeding those of person A.
- If people in the process don't use some agreed colour coding (some task is written down and when complete it's usually overdrawn with a marker of a specific colour) on the paper document, others aren't able to see the state of the process (document) without reading all the details handwritten on it or asking the person executing the task.

## Requirements (not must, but should)

- Instead of working with a physical paper document I'd like to have it in digital form (i.e. Google Docs so that doc history is also present) so it can't be lost/forgotten and all collaborators are able to check its state at any time without bothering other people
- If the process would be managed without an actual document in digital form (like using kanban boards) it still needs to be created/printed at the end for storage purposes. In this case an automated creation would be preferred.
- A way of quickly glancing over all incomplete processes without opening documents so that person A (manager) can easily follow up with other people to further outstanding tasks.
- Service is online and preferably free

## Services I was thinking about

- I was thinking of using boards like **Trello + Google Docs**, but I'm not sure how deeply Google Docs are integrated into it (just as attachments to cards/tasks isn't enough). The finished card (wishful) requirement of printing an actual document seems to be something non-trivial.
- Using **Google Drive + App Scripts** (I'm a developer) to accomplish this. I was thinking of using Sheets for process management and scripts to auto generate a doc using some template document at the end when a process is finished.
- Using **Google Docs**, so that the document would still be created and edited by all people within the process. The problem I'm seeing here is that checking the state requires reading documents' content and that you can't share as editable just parts of the document, but only as a whole. Maybe Apps script could be used to automatically rename the file by appending current state?
- Haven't evaluated **MS Office Online** collaboration features if they offer anything beyond the shortcomings of Google Docs.

##### What service would you suggest that seems to be a good starting point for my process management and would solve the above as much as possible?

Thank you for reading this far and helping me.